# Configuration activity not working when widget is clicked

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

I have been trying to figure out this problem for ages and tried at least 10 solutions on stack overflow with no success.

I have created a Widget class that display some numbers on the home screen which updates every 5 minutes. The Widget is a button, which when the user clicks on it, the configuration activity is loaded up so the widget can be updated.

When I create the widget the first time, the configuration activity opens and users can type in the text box. Once the configuration is done, the widget is updated - all working as intended. However when the button is pressed the configuration activity does not launch again. The weird thing is that when I re run the app via android studio or reboot the phone, the activity can be launched. I think it has to do with it not updating the button pressing for some reason, but I cannot find where to fix it.

I have seen a couple of similar questions that have my issue and tried their solutions but it does not work at all. I am pretty new at android programming so I might have overlooked something. I have hard coded some variable pretty badly which needed to be changed but I don't think that would affect the launching of the activity.

Here is my WidgetProvider, Configuration Activity classes and the manifest.

LPWidget.java

```java
public class LPWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "ExampleWidget";
static int nowLP = LPWidgetConfigureActivity.currentLP ;
static int maxNowLP = LPWidgetConfigureActivity.maxLP;
static boolean notfirstTime = false;


/**
 * Custom Intent name that is used by the AlarmManager to tell us to update the clock once per second.
 */
public static String CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE = "doingitnow.simplelptracker.CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Clock update");
        // Get the widget manager and ids for this widget provider, then call the shared
        // clock update method.
        ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), getClass().getName());
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        int ids[] = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);
        for (int appWidgetID: ids) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetID);

        }
    }
}

private PendingIntent createClockTickIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    return pendingIntent;
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    super.onDisabled(context);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Widget Provider disabled. Turning off timer");
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(createClockTickIntent(context));
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Widget Provider enabled.  Starting timer to update widget every second");
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 10000, createClockTickIntent(context));
}


@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Updating Example Widgets.");

    // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this
    // provider
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.lpwidget);
        Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, LPWidgetConfigureActivity.class);
        configIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        configIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        configIntent.setData(Uri.parse(configIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);


        // Update The clock label using a shared method
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }
}

public static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
    if (notfirstTime) { //if it is not the first time, update
        if (nowLP < maxNowLP) { //if the nowLP less than the max, add one.
            nowLP = nowLP + 1;

        }
    }
    notfirstTime = true;

    String StringNowLP = "LP: " + Integer.toString(nowLP) + "/" + Integer.toString(maxNowLP);

    RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.lpwidget);
    updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.button, StringNowLP);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, updateViews);
}
```

LPWidgetConfigureActivity.java

```java
public class LPWidgetConfigureActivity extends Activity {

static int currentLP = 20;
static int maxLP = 50;

int mAppWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;


public LPWidgetConfigureActivity() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    // Set the result to CANCELED.  This will cause the widget host to cancel
    // out of the widget placement if the user presses the back button.
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);

    setContentView(R.layout.lpwidget_configure);


    // Find the widget id from the intent.
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }

    // If this activity was started with an intent without an app widget ID, finish with an error.
    if (mAppWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
        finish();
    }
    final EditText currentLPText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.currentLPText);
    final EditText MaxLPText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MaxLPText);
    Button applyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button);
    applyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Context context = LPWidgetConfigureActivity.this;
            try { //No empty text - update all
                String intcurrentLP = currentLPText.getText().toString();
                String intMaxLP = MaxLPText.getText().toString();
                currentLP = Integer.parseInt(intcurrentLP);
                maxLP = Integer.parseInt(intMaxLP);
                LPWidget.nowLP = currentLP;
                LPWidget.maxNowLP = maxLP;

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                try { //Empty currentLP text - update MaxLP
                    String intMaxLP = MaxLPText.getText().toString();
                    maxLP = Integer.parseInt(intMaxLP);
                    LPWidget.maxNowLP = maxLP;
                    Context toastcontext = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "Max LP is updated only";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(toastcontext, text, duration);
                    toast.show();
                } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                    try { //empty MaxLP text - update currentLP
                        String intcurrentLP = currentLPText.getText().toString();
                        currentLP = Integer.parseInt(intcurrentLP);
                        LPWidget.nowLP = currentLP;
                        Context toastcontext = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = "Current LP is updated only";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(toastcontext, text, duration);
                        toast.show();
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e2) { //All empty text - No changes
                        Context toastcontext = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = "No Text Inputted - No Changes done";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(toastcontext, text, duration);
                        toast.show();

                    }
                }
            }

            LPWidget.notfirstTime = false;

            // It is the responsibility of the configuration activity to update the app widget
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            LPWidget.updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, mAppWidgetId);

            // Make sure we pass back the original appWidgetId
            Intent resultValue = new Intent();
            resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);

            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="doingitnow.simplelptracker" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WallpaperSettings" >

    <activity
        android:name=".LPMainPage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_lpmain_page"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WallpaperSettings" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".LPWidgetConfigureActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WallpaperSettings" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".LPWidget" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="doingitnow.simplelptracker.CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/lpwidget_info" />
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".LPUpdateActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_lpupdate"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WallpaperSettings">
        <intent-filter>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much pain, I managed to figure out why the config activity never ran.

Firstly, the `calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);` means that once the alarm was set, it waited 10 seconds until the alarm was fired. This means if I were to finish my config activity before 10 seconds, It would not fire the alarm and the update until 10 seconds was up. If the activity was done 10 seconds after alarm, the activity would work as normal.

However when the config activity was updating the widget `LPWidget.updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, mAppWidgetId);` would only update what was on screen and not create the remote view for the button, since it was in the `onUpdate()` function. Since that function would never update since I set the `updateperiodmillis`in the info provider to 0, the remote view would be launched after the alarm update. Furthermore, two Remote Views were made, which cause more confusion, so merging the two Remote Views I had and place it in the `updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, mAppWidgetId);` would mean the the button can be pressed and the widget is updated on screen.